# How to get multiple values from HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I need to get multiple values from my HTML.

```
<img class="tested" style='display:none' data-src=https://sATES.jpg>
<img class="tested" style='display:none' data-src=https://sATES2.jpg>
<img class="tested" style='display:none' data-src=https://sATES3.jpg>
```

```js
var elements = $(".tested").data("src");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements);
}
```

The problem is that I'm only on getting 1 URL. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: either you have made some silly mistakes here (which happens to everyone) or you simply have not made a real attempt to learn javascript

Comment: you are only returing the variable `elements` which is an array I assume? You are looping the array, but never defining which element you want to return (or show in the console). Try replacing `console.log(elements);` with ´console.log(elements[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple `.tested` elements, so you need to loop over each one to get the required `data` attribute from it. Try this:

```
$(".tested").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var elements = $(".tested");
 $(elements).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data("src"));
 });
```

Comment: Copy of the above answer? That too without an explanation?

Comment: You don't need to wrap `elements` in jQuery object as it is already jQuery obj.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery [**map**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
var srcs = $('img.tested').map(function() { return $(this).data('src'); });

console.log(srcs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="tested" style="display:none" data-src="https://sATES.jpg">
<img class="tested" style="display:none" data-src="https://sATES2.jpg">
<img class="tested" style="display:none" data-src="https://sATES3.jpg">
```